# lock the application role if users enter wrong password more than three times

Tags: sql, security, role

I have a winform C# application which uses sql server 2005 express.

I am using application role to grant user to access the database.

A Form opens asking for username & password from the user.

This username & password is of the application role which i have created beforehand in a database.

I want that if the user enters wrong password or username more than 3 times then the .net application shows that your account has been locked and exits. how do i do it?

Comment: Take care not to lock out db admin this way.

Comment: @blaze, am not talking about the db admin , but about an end user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use Windows Authentication? I've never used an application role.

Every user would have the same username and password with application roles...

Edit:

You can use [SQL Server logins](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189751.aspx) and enforce password lockouts via [group policy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189751.aspx). This means each user can have a different login

Comment: sir, you mean to say that i cannot use multiple application roles ?

Comment: also in case of windows authentication, if any user sits on the system & knows its password, then he would start my application and insert wrong data in the database. in this type of case what would you refer?